# Angular 5 project huge deference in size of vendor bundle

Tags: angular

I have a small Angular 5 project, is it normal to have this bundle sizes difference between dev and prod environments??

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which files are you comparing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many reason for that result :

build in target production mode make lot of optimization :

- AOT compilation will remove angular "compiler" from bundle who are the huge part of Angular framework.
- you don't have any embed sourcemap.
- all code are minified
- embed css are extracted and move to external CSS file (instead of embed on js file) (see `extract-css`)
- Webpack remove unused code from your output. (see `build-optimizer`)

If this project have to be put online, i highly recommand you to activate [gzip mod](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html) on your webserver. This will reduce size to something like `400ko`

[official documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#--dev-vs---prod-builds)